# Known method to update custom property when default property changed?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

For an addon I am trying to develop, I need to reference bones as a custom property in my property groups. This I have done by using a StringProperty and a prop_search in the UI layout. Annoyance can occur however when the name of the referenced bone is changed. The custom StringProperty will retain the original name of the bone and not be updated to match the new name automatically.

An existing example of something behaving in the way I would like is the bone.parent property, which is automatically updated to match the name of the parent bone when its name is updated. I looked at the python scripts which draw these properties in the UI, and it uses the exact same prop_search functionality as I do. I am left to assume that the implementation of the property itself is in the C code however as I found nothing on the functionality for automatically updating the reference.

How can I replicate this behavior in my custom property? Is there a feature in the API I could use which does this automatically that I have somehow missed? Are there any working examples of this which people have in their addons that I can look at? Any information is helpful.

Comment: bone.parent is a pointer property with type Bone (you can check with `bpy.types.Bone.bl_rna.properties["parent"].fixed_type`). But you can't make one of those yourself, since PointerProperty(type=T) requires T to be an ID and Bone isn't... Maybe you could try "inverting" your design; store a custom prop on the bone, instead of a custom prop that references the bone.

Comment: Bones have the problem of being unable to have fully functional custom Pointer or Collection properties. Ignoring that problem however, it would work only for most, but not all cases where I need to reference a bone in a custom property.

Comment: I checked how eg. object.parent_bone (a StringProperty) worked, and [Blender does just iterate over all objects and fix them up when a bone is renamed](https://github.com/sobotka/blender/blob/67b657f07c96c5782ebf603ab36af607168d7acb/source/blender/editors/armature/armature_naming.c#L156). You could use [msgbus](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html) to subscribe to bone renames and do that.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll let you know where this goes...

Comment: @scurest The msgbus module works pretty well for what I wanted. It's not perfect as the msgbus callback seems to count as a separate action from the actual renaming of the bone when undoing/redoing, but it otherwise works just the way I would like. Feel free to post a proper answer and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.